# Fortran OpenMP with multiple simultaneous reductions results in seg fault

Tags: fortran, openmp, reduction

I used the intel openMP tutorials a while back. I wrote the pi Program reduction and am working on a fortran code using openMP now. I want to sum 4 quantities at once with the reduction clause. the code looks like so:

```
call omp_set_num_threads(num_threads)
write(*,*) "number of parallel threads"
write(*,*) num_threads


N_init = 1200
N_t    = 1250

filename = 'POD_input/POD_avg.dat'

io = 0
nCell = 0
open(UNIT = 10, FILE = filename, STATUS = 'OLD', form = 'formatted')
    do
        read(10,*, end=67) nonsense, nonsense, nonsense, nonsense, nonsense, nonsense, nonsense, nonsense, nonsense, nonsense, nonsense
        nCell = nCell + 1
    end do
67 close(10)

allocate(eig(nCell))
allocate(wr(nCell))
allocate(wi(nCell))
allocate(work(4*nCell))

allocate(R_Corr(nCell, nCell))
allocate(U_Corr(nCell, nCell))
allocate(V_Corr(nCell, nCell))
allocate(P_Corr(nCell, nCell))

allocate(R_Tot(nCell, nCell))
allocate(U_Tot(nCell, nCell))
allocate(V_Tot(nCell, nCell))
allocate(P_Tot(nCell, nCell))

allocate(R_Fin(nCell, nCell))
allocate(U_Fin(nCell, nCell))
allocate(V_Fin(nCell, nCell))
allocate(P_Fin(nCell, nCell))

allocate(x(nCell))
allocate(y(nCell))
allocate(A(nCell))

allocate(Rho(nCell))
allocate(U(nCell))
allocate(V(nCell))
allocate(P(nCell))

allocate(R_x(nCell))
allocate(U_x(nCell))
allocate(V_x(nCell))
allocate(P_x(nCell))

allocate(R_c(nCell))
allocate(U_c(nCell))
allocate(V_c(nCell))
allocate(P_c(nCell))

allocate(R_av(nCell))
allocate(U_av(nCell))
allocate(V_av(nCell))
allocate(P_av(nCell))


open(UNIT = 10, FILE = filename, STATUS = 'OLD', form = 'formatted')
    do iCell = 1, nCell
        read(10,*)  x(iCell), y(iCell), A(iCell), nonsense, nonsense, nonsense, nonsense, R_av(iCell), U_av(iCell), V_av(iCell), P_av(iCell)
    end do
close(10)

filename = 'POD_output/POD_Mesh.dat'

open(UNIT = 10, FILE = filename, STATUS = 'unknown', form = 'unformatted', access='stream')
    write(10) nCell
    write(10) x(:)
    write(10) y(:)
close(10)

R_Tot = 0.0_dp
U_Tot = 0.0_dp
V_Tot = 0.0_dp
P_Tot = 0.0_dp

write(*,*) "begin correlation"

!$OMP PARALLEL DO REDUCTION(+:R_Tot, U_Tot, V_Tot, P_Tot) private(i, j, nonsense, filename, num, iCell, iTime, R_x, R_C, R_Corr, U_x, U_C, U_Corr, V_x, V_C, V_Corr, P_x, P_C, P_Corr)
   do iTime = N_init,N_t
       write(*,*) "inside loop"
       filename = 'POD_input/POD_input.'
       write(num,'(I6.6)') iTime
       filename = trim(adjustl(filename))//trim(adjustl(num))//trim(adjustl('.dat'))
       ! Read file

       write(*,*) "read file"
       open(UNIT = 10, FILE = filename, STATUS = 'OLD', form = 'formatted')
           do iCell = 1, nCell
               read(10,*) nonsense, nonsense, nonsense, R_x(iCell), U_x(iCell), V_x(iCell), P_x(iCell)
           end do
       close(10)

       R_x = R_x-R_av
       U_x = U_x-U_av
       V_x = V_x-V_av
       P_x = P_x-P_av

       R_C(:) = R_x(:)*sqrt(A(:))
       U_C(:) = U_x(:)*sqrt(A(:))
       V_C(:) = V_x(:)*sqrt(A(:))
       P_C(:) = P_x(:)*sqrt(A(:))


       do i = 1, nCell
           do j =1, nCell
               R_Corr(i,j) = R_C(i)*R_C(j)
               U_Corr(i,j) = U_C(i)*U_C(j)
               V_Corr(i,j) = V_C(i)*V_C(j)
               P_Corr(i,j) = P_C(i)*P_C(j)
           end do
       end do


       R_Tot =  R_Tot + R_Corr
       U_Tot =  U_Tot + U_Corr
       V_Tot =  V_Tot + V_Corr
       P_Tot =  P_Tot + P_Corr
   end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

I get a segmentation fault error even when running with 1 thread. what can I do to debug this or fix it. thank you.

EDIT: Included more code for ease of assistance

Comment: does it work with gfortran?

Comment: Openmp compile option may stop the compiler from correcting loop nesting. Array reduction may not make sense here.

Comment: It does not work with gfortran for other compiling issues. tim, how should i fix this so that i can loop over my time steps and reads then? Thanks

Comment: Without a [mcve] showing otherwise I think that `ncell` does not have the value that it should have.

Comment: Hi Mark, It doesn't work even if I hard code in a value in place of nCell. So I do not believe that is the issue. I have edited the submission to include the preceding code to the current snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a similar problem once. The used arrays might be large so the stack size is not enough large to fit these data. I sugest you to increase the stack size. I'm using linux and I generally do it through the cmd `ulimit -s unlimited`.

In addition when you use a reduction clause with openMP, each threads create a private copy of the variables targeted by the reduction clause. These data are placed on a private stack that size is generally limited to a few MB. to overwrite this limitation, assuming that you are a Linux user, you can run, for instance, the cmd `export OMP_STACKSIZE=50m` to set the private stack size to 50MB. The value 50m could be changed as function of the hardware limitation and the size of your arrays.

It is important to mention that reduction clause might be not effecient at all with large arrays.